# MS Access 2007 - Hyperlink with a text string sub-address from a form

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink

I have no problem with creating a hyperlink to a url but I have been unable to Concatenate the sub-address. If I hard code it into the url, it works fine. But I am looking to pull the subaddress from the Form data.

Thanks for any advice! I am a newbie and explicit directions will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code you are using to your question along with the string variable values present and expected.    Also have you inserted the backslash(es) as required.

Comment: FollowHyperlink ("http://emma.msrb.org/SecurityView/SecurityDetails.aspx?cusip="),Cusip

Comment: FollowHyperlink ("http://emma.msrb.org/SecurityView/SecurityDetails.aspx?cusip="),Cusip    For Some reason, it is inserting a # before the Cusip that is causing the url to not load.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I finally figured it out: Application.FollowHyperlink ("http://emma.msrb.org/SecurityView/SecurityDetailsTrades.aspx?cusip=") + [Cusip]    Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity for the next guy (because the Asker has sort of buried the answer in comments):

```
Application.FollowHyperlink _
    ("emma.msrb.org/SecurityView/SecurityDetailsTrades.aspx?cusip=";) + [Cusip]
```

I'll also note, I'm not sure what you are doing (Given the URL), but it may not be the most secure way of doing it.